# Use the output of Select in a Table with a script bash

Tags: shell-script

I have a issue.

I build a script can connect to database and select a value from table

But i can't get only the result

this is my script

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    mysql -p<pass-db> -e "select id from test where concat(upper(trim(firstname)), ' ', upper(trim(lastname)))=upper('$line')" mydatanase 
    echo ${IDS[j]}
    let "j++"
done < employees.txt
```

the output of echo is

```
id
78
```

i would only get the "78" , not the name of colomun

Comment: Hello @YOU CHT LEE is the output of `echo` only two lines? or a series of lines: Id then number  then id after then number and so on ?

Answer (score 0):

Invoke mysql with -N to turn off column headers, i.e. `mysql -N`